# How can I just "skip" incoming mail notification?

Tags: mail.app, email, notifications

When I get an email, macos notification system shows a banner like image below and two options are available: `reply` or `delete`.

[image]

This is useful, but sometimes I want to just skip the banner because it takes top right corner for some seconds and I just want to clear it away. (I know 'alert' has options for `close` but I do not like it)

[image]

How can I just skip the incoming mail banner by mouse or keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can drag to the right to dismiss it without taking any action.